# How to change column name from date to Month Name-year in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the date column to month name-year, following code i am using

```
rows = []
sort = ''
for v in results:
    row = {'date':v['TimePeriod']['Start']}
    sort = v['TimePeriod']['Start']
    for i in v['Groups']:
        key = i['Keys'][0]
        if key in self.accounts:
            key = self.accounts[key][ACCOUNT_Name]
        row.update({key:int(float(i['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']))}) 
    if not v['Groups']:
        row.update({'Total':int(float(v['Total']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']))})
    rows.append(row)  

    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
        

df.set_index("Mon_Year", inplace= True)
df = df.fillna(0.0)
        
if Style == 'Change':
    dfc = df.copy()
    lastindex = None
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if lastindex:
            for i in row.index:
                try:
                    df.at[index,i] = dfc.at[index,i] - dfc.at[lastindex,i]
                except:
                    logging.exception("Error")
                    df.at[index,i] = 0
        lastindex = index
df = df.T
df = df.sort_values(sort, ascending=False)
self.reports.append({'Name':Name,'Data':df, 'Type':type})
```

and getting output as

```
2021-02-01       2021-03-01        2021-04-01
 xxxxxx            xxxxx             xxxxx
```

required output

```
Feb-2021       Mar-2021        Apr-2021
 xxxxxx            xxxxx          xxxxx
```

Can someone please help? I am new for python

Comment: can someone guide me where to put these codes in existing code

Comment: I tried the options but getting error '''dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: Unnamed: 0'

Comment: data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Temp\employees.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).strftime('%b-%Y')
print (df)

Comment: Right, you can put the code after `df` is defined.  The location you specified above seems a sensible place.  However, the return type of pd.read_csv should already be a dataframe.  Do you still need to pass it to pd.DataFrame ?

Comment: Got it to work yet ?  Feel free to let us know if any further question.

Answer (score 4):

You can reformat the column labels of date format using [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html?highlight=strftime), as follows:

#### (1) Conversion for all columns (all columns in date format):

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).strftime('%b-%Y')
```

### Demo

```
data = {'2021-02-01': [1, 2, 3], '2021-03-01': [11, 12, 13], '2021-04-01': [21, 22, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


print(df)


   2021-02-01  2021-03-01  2021-04-01
0           1          11          21
1           2          12          22
2           3          13          23


df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).strftime('%b-%Y')


print(df)


   Feb-2021  Mar-2021  Apr-2021
0         1        11        21
1         2        12        22
2         3        13        23
```

#### (2) Conversion for part of the columns only:

In real life situation, if your column labels are not all in date format and would only like to convert the relevant column labels only, you can do it as follows:

Assuming you have only 3 columns `df.columns[1:4]` with column labels in dates, you can use:

```
df.columns = df.columns[0:1].to_list() +  pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1:4]).strftime('%b-%Y').to_list() + df.columns[4:].to_list()
```

### Demo

```
data = {'ID': ['A001', 'A002', 'A003'], '2021-02-01': [1, 2, 3], '2021-03-01': [11, 12, 13], '2021-04-01': [21, 22, 23], 'Other': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

     ID  2021-02-01  2021-03-01  2021-04-01 Other
0  A001           1          11          21     a
1  A002           2          12          22     b
2  A003           3          13          23     c


df.columns = df.columns[0:1].to_list() +  pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1:4]).strftime('%b-%Y').to_list() + df.columns[4:].to_list()


print(df)


     ID  Feb-2021  Mar-2021  Apr-2021 Other
0  A001         1        11        21     a
1  A002         2        12        22     b
2  A003         3        13        23     c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `datetime` to get that datetime string in required format.

```py
from datetime import datetime

>>> datetime.strptime('2020-10-20', '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%b-%Y')
   'Oct-2020'
```

Given a dataframe like this:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'2021-02-01':[1,2,3],'2021-03-01':[10,30,15],'2021-04-01':[-0.25,2.5,-0.35]})
>>> df
   2021-02-01  2021-03-01  2021-04-01
0           1          10       -0.25
1           2          30        2.50
2           3          15       -0.35
```

First use `datetime.strptime` to convert column name string to datetime object, then use `datetime.strftime` to convert the datetime object back to string in the required format and assign it as dataframe `column` names

You can either create list of new columns names like this:

```py
>>> df.columns = list(map(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%Y'), map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'), df.columns.to_list())))
```

Or you can directly call `map` method on the `dataframe.columns` attribute

```py
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')).map(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%Y'))
```

**PS**: Remember the order of `map`, for python's native `map` function, it is from inner most to outer most, for dataframe's `map` method, it's from left to right.

**OUTPUT**:

```py
   Feb-2021  Mar-2021  Apr-2021
0         1        10     -0.25
1         2        30      2.50
2         3        15     -0.35
```